# Convert numerous inputs values into array of values

Tags: javascript, html

I have several textbox as below:

```
<input type="text" id="name1" name="name1">
<input type="text" id="name2" name="name2">
<input type="text" id="name3" name="name3">
<input type="text" id="name4" name="name4">
```

Need to pass save the values in array (name[]) and then I want to receive the data as "name[]"

The server side file will use PHP $_POST['name'] to fetch data.

Thanks.

Comment: change the name to `name="name[]"`

Comment: This will depend on what language you are using on the server side. Could you [edit] your question to include this detail?

Comment: check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/  function

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny. It seem your answer is the most simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the many solutions can be

```
function myFunction() {
  var result = [];
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("[name^=name]");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length ; i++){
    result.push(x[i].value);
  }
}
```